# Postgres: trying to fix some unicode encoding issues

Tags: postgresql

I've got a postgres 8.4 database with a few mangled characters in one of the columns on a table. For example, the word "don't" gets displayed within `psql` as:

```
donÃ¢\u0080\u0099t
```

I want to be able to dig out these odd characters and replace them with simple `'` or `"` alternatives. However, I'm having a bit of a job getting either `~` or `LIKE` to be able to pull the correct rows in, let alone be able to replace them.

The database is UTF8 and the `client_encoding` is also set to UTF8. I've tried selecting `\u` string and `\x` strings, but can't seem to get anything reliable. For example, all of the following queries return 0 rows or `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x80`

```
select col from tab where col like '%\u0080\u0099%';
select col from tab where col ~'\u0080\u0099';
select col from tab where col like '%\x8099%';
select col from tab where col ~'\x8099';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If what you see is `donÃ¢\u0080\u0099t` then those are **literal** backslashes in your table, not escape sequences.

Try to double the backslashes to get literal ones:

```
select col from tab where col ~~ E'%\\u0080%';
```

And use the [proper `E''` syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) for PostgreSQL 8.4 with that.

Comment: Brilliant! This works on the `\u0080` characters, I just need to replace the odd characters before that now. `psql` is printing those on resultsets as `It<C3><A2>s`, so I'm assuming I'm just looking for unicode chars `c3` and `a2`? Google tells me these characters equate to `â`, but I'm not sure what escape sequence I need to use to find this - `\uc3a2`?

Comment: @growse: It's hard to tell what *should* be there. It very much depends on how the text was mangled, and there is a myriad of possible ways. Some detective work may be needed. For instance, your example `donÃ¢\u0080\u0099t` looks very much like it should be `don't`. A case for `replace (col, E'Ã¢\\u0080\\u0099','''')`. Be sure to view the results in a `SELECT` statement before applying with `UPDATE`.

Comment: Also, if you want to insert the character `â`, you can just insert it as is - you are using UTF-8 as server and client encoding.